# XSLT change a single attribute

Tags: xslt, attributes

I  have this input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soa:Label identifier="1f9b3588-d069-416b-b7da-e32d203c5bac" name="Label" description="" leftaligncheckboxes="false" instance="c9a32ab9-248e-485f-8f09-b2dd6bc574f0" signature="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" menuname="" itemmode="closed" xmlns:soa="urn:jondoe.net:soa:core">
    <soa:Parameter type="string" identifier="a2eecb22-53aa-4af4-a7ee-f8a97108d777" bindable="True" name="FilePath" enabled="true" disableable="false" browsable="true" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1" maxlines="-1">d:\folder\file1.txt<soa:Default></soa:Default>
        <soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
    </soa:Parameter>
</soa:Label>
```

it's a table that contains a single parameters "FilePath" that changes on each output file. I need to insert the value "path" in the output file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sequence path="d:\folder\file1.txt" rate="24" failOnGap="false">
    <OpenSupport timeout="30" enabled="true"/>
</Sequence>
```

I tried to do a stylesheet that I don't publish to avoid yet a poor figure :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, neither your source document nor your stylesheet is well-formed XML, so you clearly have some way to go.

There are lots of things wrong with the code you've shown us, but the most glaring is that you can't use xsl:value-of within an attribute. Instead, you want an attribute value template: something like

```
<Sequence path="{parameter1}">
```

But I've no idea what `parameter1` is supposed to be.

**Later**

Now you've given us an input file and output file, the transformation is very straightforward.

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soa="urn:jondoe.net:soa:core"
    exclude-result-prefixes="soa"
    version="1.0">
 <xsl:template match="/">
   <Sequence path="{//soa:parameter[@name='FilePath']}"
             rate="24" failOnGap="false">
     <OpenSupport timeout="30" enabled="true"/>
   </Sequence>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Good morning Michael, thank you for the answer,

Comment: good morning Michael, thank you for the answer, yes, my stylesheet sucks :-), actually I'm not expert on XSLT as you can see, I have to export the xml as the sample one, this unusual xml starts another application, the variable here is the value "Path" that changes any time so I have to find a way to change the attribute path on each xml, it  could be "D:\folder\File1", be "D:\folder2\File2"..

Comment: To be brutal, you're not doing yourself any favours here. There are simple spelling mistakes in your question, but more importantly you simply haven't told us clearly what you want to achieve. Put yourself in the shoes of someone trying to answer your question: they can't help you get to your destination if you don't say what that destination is.

Comment: okI have an input file

Comment: the input file is: